# Looking to replace my Ubiquiti USG with something faster

Tags: router, gateway

I have all Ubiquiti hardware so I want to stick with it.  The USG is hopeless for security in that if I enable the Threat Management System the throughput drops to 85Mbs (there is a warning is the setup about it).  So, I don't have it on.

I am looking at these two

1. [Ubiquiti UniFi UDM-PRO Dream Machine Pro 10G HyperFibre Router, 10G SFP+ x2](https://www.pbtech.co.nz/product/NETUBI2201/Ubiquiti-UniFi-UDM-PRO-Dream-Machine-Pro-10G-Hyper)
2. [Ubiquiti UniFi UDM-SE Dream Machine Special Edition 10G HyperFibre Router, 10G SFP+ x2](https://www.pbtech.co.nz/product/NETUBI2202/Ubiquiti-UniFi-UDM-SE-Dream-Machine-Special-Editio)

I can't figure out why the second one is more expensive (apart from the SSD and POE support). $700 is a lot to pay for this.

My priorities are

1. Speed with IDS enabled
2. NVR is a bonus as I have to replace my Vivotek system sometime, but I think that both have it with external disks
3. I think the first one has integrated cloudkey, which is beneficial only in getting rid of a network device.

| Specification | UDM-PRO | UDM-SE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Dimensions | 442.4 x 43.7 x 285.6 mm | 442.4 x 43.7 x 285.6 mm (17.42 x 1.72 x 11.24") |
| Weight | 3.90 kg or 3.99 kg With Brackets | 4.95 kg (10.91 lb) |
| Interfaces | Networking; (8) 10/100/1000 RJ45 LAN Ports, (1) 10/100/1000 RJ45 WAN Port, (1) 1/10G SFP+ LAN Port, (1) 1/10G SFP+ WAN Port | (1) WAN: 2.5 GbE RJ45 port, (8) LAN: 1 GbE RJ45 ports,(1) WAN: 10G SFP+ (1) LAN: 10G SFP+ |
| Management | Ethernet In-Band, (1) Bluetooth BLE | Ethernet, Bluetooth |
| POE Interfaces |  | (2) PoE+ IEEE 802.3at (pair A 1, 2+; 3, 6-), (6) PoE IEEE 802.3af (pair A 1, 2+; 3, 6-) |
| IDS/IPS Throughput | 3.5 Gbps | 3.5 Gbps |
| Processor | Quad ARM Cortex-A57 Core at 1.7 GHz | Quad-Core ARM® Cortex®-A57 at 1.7 GHz |
| System Memory | 4 GB DDR4 | 4 GB DDR4 |
| On-Board Flash Storage | 16 GB eMMC | 16 GB eMMC Integrated 128 GB SSD |
| Max Power Consumption | 33W | 50W |
| LEDs | HDD Activity, RJ45 Link/Speed/Activity, SFP+ Link/Speed/Activity | (1) 1.3" touchscreen |
| ESD/EMP Protection | Air: ± 16 kV, Contact: ± 12 kV | Air: ± 15 kV, contact: ± 8 kV |
| Operating Temperature | -10 to 40° C (14 to 104° F) | -10 to 40° C (14 to 104° F) |
| Operating Humidity | 5 to 95% Noncondensing | 5 - 95% noncondensing |
| Certifications | CE, FCC, IC | CE, FCC, IC |

**Concern** With external HDDs for NVR, presumably they can't be on RAID.

Comment: The only real difference with the special edition (SE) is the PoE. On their webisite, its only 100 USD different. It's still cheaper to just buy PoE injectors.

Comment: and the 2.5 gig wan port, though least in my local market, I've seen ONE 2 gig, single output offer, and there's no details on it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I made the table in my question for comparison, I realised that there were two differences.  The UDM-SE has an SSD and POE's.  Downunder the difference in price was $700.

- I did not need more POE's (and its cheaper to get them another way)
- I discussed with tech support for the reseller and he assured me that both have the same throughput after enabling the IDS (Intrusion Detection System)

So, I have purchased the UDM-PRO